# Android - Extrac SameSite=Strict cookie from Webview or URL

Tags: android, cookies

I'm using the following code within the onPageFinished() of a WebViewClient to read the cookies . But some cookies are set "SameSite=Strict", which I cannot get using the method below:

```
 @Override
 public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
     String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
     Log.d(TAG, "All the cookies in a string:" + cookies);
 }
```

Can anybody tell me how to get the cookies which are set "SameSite=Strict" ?

Comment: I've submitted some bug reports regarding this issue: (1) https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=780491&can=2&q=samesite&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified and (2) https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68756461

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is [officially a bug in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=780491#c4) and needs to be (hopefully will be) fixed there.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in WebView 72.  If you're not getting the `SameSite` `Lax` or `Strict` cookies, you need to update the System WebView implementation to any version >= 72

David's post has a link to the bug and I have just confirmed after updating from version 70 to 80 that the `CookieManager` instance is now getting ALL cookies.

Comment: Updating the web view wont fix the problem .updated issues still  there

Comment: @LibinThomas hmmm.. interesting.  it fixed for me.  however, what I ended up doing was creating a login screen then sharing the cookies among webviews after I get them from the login screen.  It's sloppy to require the users to update their webview anyway https://github.com/hexag0d/BitChute_Mobile_Android_BottomNav/blob/FinalWebViewV/VideoDownloaderDonationUpdate/Web/Login.cs